# Display a message when ajax response is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created one simple table with ajax response.Here I am getting `approvedOn` and `approvedBy` as `null` .
[image]
But I don't want to display it as `null`.I want to display it as `pending`.Any suggestion?

```
 var leaveList = [{
  "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "causual",
     "leaveOn": "12-02-2017",
     "duration": "5 days",
     "status": "approved",
     "approvedOn": "null",
     "approvedBy": "null"
 }, {
     "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "privileged",
     "leaveOn": "14-03-2017",
     "duration": "8 days",
     "status": "pending",
     "approvedOn": "13-02-2017",
     "approvedBy": "HR"
 }];
 $(document).ready(function() {
     leaveTable()
 });

 function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```

Complete code:https://jsfiddle.net/tytzuckz/4/

Comment: Can you amend the response to include `null` as a value instead of a string? If so you can use the logical OR operator, `||`, to coalesce the value

Comment: In your example the `approvedOn`  contains a string with the literal `null`, but not the value `null`. Are you sure that it is returned that way from the server? The server should return `"approvedOn": null` (without the quotes around the `null`) and not `"approvedOn": "null"`.

Comment: Now that you've added the image of the object you can see that `null` is being provided directly, not as a string as your question originally showed in the code. Also note that the property casing is different - this is crucial in JS as it's case sensitive

Comment: please check my code here https://jsfiddle.net/sagar_arora/tytzuckz/13/ it solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require from the object you receive you can use the logical OR operator (`||`) to coalesce the `null` value as required. Also note that the code you've shown has different property names to the image of the object you showed in the console. Make sure the names you use are correct as JS is case sensitive. Try this:

```
(leaveList[i].approvedOn || 'pending')
```

```js
var leaveList = [{
  "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
  "levType": "causual",
  "leaveOn": "12-02-2017",
  "duration": "5 days",
  "status": "approved",
  "approvedOn": null,
  "approvedBy": null
}, {
  "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
  "levType": "privileged",
  "leaveOn": "14-03-2017",
  "duration": "8 days",
  "status": "pending",
  "approvedOn": "13-02-2017",
  "approvedBy": "HR"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  leaveTable()
});

function leaveTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
    var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + (leaveList[i].approvedOn || 'pending') + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + (leaveList[i].approvedBy || 'pending') + '</td><tr>';

    $('#levListTable').append(tab)
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="colorBlue">
    <tr>
      <td>S.No</td>
      <td>Applied On</td>
      <td>Leave Type</td>
      <td>Leave On</td>
      <td>Duration</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Approved On</td>
      <td>Approved By</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="levListTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use inline condition like this :

```js
var leaveList = [{
     "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "causual",
     "leaveOn": "12-02-2017",
     "duration": "5 days",
     "status": "approved",
     "approvedOn": "null",
     "approvedBy": "null"
 }, {
     "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "privileged",
     "leaveOn": "14-03-2017",
     "duration": "8 days",
     "status": "pending",
     "approvedOn": "13-02-2017",
     "approvedBy": "HR"
 }];
 $(document).ready(function() {
     leaveTable()
 });

 function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
     
         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + (leaveList[i].approvedOn == 'null' || leaveList[i].approvedOn == '' ? 'Pending' : leaveList[i].approvedOn) + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + (leaveList[i].approvedBy == 'null' || leaveList[i].approvedBy == '' ? 'Pending' : leaveList[i].approvedBy) + '</td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="colorBlue">
        <tr>
            <td>S.No</td>
            <td>Applied On</td>
            <td>Leave Type</td>
            <td>Leave On</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Approved On</td>
            <td>Approved By</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="levListTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check as in:

```
if (leaveList[i].approvedOn === 'null') {
    leaveList[i].approvedOn = 'pending';
}

if (leaveList[i].approvedBy === 'null') {
    leaveList[i].approvedBy = 'pending';
}
```

within your for loop; that should enable you achieve it.

As such, your new `leaveTable()` function is:

```
function leaveTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
    if (leaveList[i].approvedOn === 'null') {
      leaveList[i].approvedOn = 'pending';
    }
    if (leaveList[i].approvedBy === 'null') {
      leaveList[i].approvedBy = 'pending';
    }
    var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><tr>';
    $('#levListTable').append(tab)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function as this.

```
function leaveTable() {
  if (leaveList.length==0){
    var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td colspan="8" style="text-align: center">Pending..</td></tr>';
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
      var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><tr>';
    }
  }
  $('#levListTable').append(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function as below and call it when you render table ..

**Try below code**

```js
 var leaveList = [{
     "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "causual",
     "leaveOn": "12-02-2017",
     "duration": "5 days",
     "status": "approved",
     "approvedOn": "null",
     "approvedBy": "null"
 }, {
     "appliedOn": "12-02-2017",
     "levType": "privileged",
     "leaveOn": "14-03-2017",
     "duration": "8 days",
     "status": "pending",
     "approvedOn": "13-02-2017",
     "approvedBy": "HR"
 }];
 $(document).ready(function() {
     leaveTable()
 });

 function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + GetValue(leaveList[i].approvedOn) + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + GetValue(leaveList[i].approvedBy) + '</td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
 
 function GetValue(dbVal){
 
  if(dbVal.toString() == "null"){
   return "pending";
  }
  else
  {
   return dbVal;
  }
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="colorBlue">
        <tr>
            <td>S.No</td>
            <td>Applied On</td>
            <td>Leave Type</td>
            <td>Leave On</td>
            <td>Duration</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Approved On</td>
            <td>Approved By</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="levListTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

Just make some changes in below function:

```
function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {

            var approvedOn = leaveList[i].approvedOn;
            if(leaveList[i].approvedOn == "null"){
            approvedOn = 'Pending';
        }

        var approvedBy = leaveList[i].approvedBy;
            if(leaveList[i].approvedBy == "null"){
            approvedBy = 'Pending';
        }
         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + approvedBy + '</td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```

Check here working [JS Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/sagar_arora/tytzuckz/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Check for null while looping using ternary operator.

```
 var approvedOn = leaveList[i].approvedOn =='null'?'pending': leaveList[i].approvedOn;
 var approvedBy =  leaveList[i].approvedBy =='null'?'pending': leaveList[i].approvedBy;
```

[Updated working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/tytzuckz/14/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple condition can help in this case. Here's the updated `leaveTable()` function.

```
function leaveTable() {
 for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {    
     var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + ((!leaveList[i].approvedOn || leaveList[i].approvedOn === "null") ? "Pending" : leaveList[i].approvedOn)  + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + ((!leaveList[i].approvedBy || leaveList[i].approvedBy === "null") ? "Pending" : leaveList[i].approvedBy) + '</td><tr>';
     $('#levListTable').append(tab)
 }}
```